# Prolog Sorting approach

Tags: prolog

Hı guys.I have a problem about prolog example.I have written following fact and rule to my database file but my database file doesn^t work while I compile it.Do you have any idea?
The error that I get is singleton variables

```
ordered([B]).
ordered(H|[H2|T]):-
   H=<H2,
   ordered([H2|T]).
```

Comment: My query is ordered([1,2,3]).

Comment: may be **ordered([H,H2|T])** instead of **ordered(H|[H2|T])**

Comment: THANKS for answering.I solved it.I write "_ "instead of B  in the first line.

Comment: Don't forget `ordered([])`

Comment: This problem is specific to SWI. In ISO conforming systems like SICStus or GNU,`ordered(H|[H2|T])` is invalid syntax regardless of the operator declaration for `|`.

Answer (score 0):

The "singleton variable" warning is warning you that in the clause

```
ordered([B]).
```

the variable `B` only appears once, i.e., is not used to bind values between different calls, i.e., can serve no purpose. This is usually the result of a typo or from forgetting to make an intended change, so the top-level issues a warning. The usual way to use singleton variables for the easy of reading without triggering a warning is to prefix it with an underscore: `_B`.

But this is unrelated to the real problem with your code. A singleton variable will not cause any problems, it's just a matter of style or a way of warning of a typographical error. As @jol76 notes, the real problem with your code is that `H|[H2|T]` is not the correct notation for matching a list's first to elements and it's tail. The notation is `[H,H2|T]`. I think of the notation as `[a,n,y,' ',n,u,m,b,e,r,' ',o,f,' ',e,l,e,m,e,n,t,s,' ',a,n,d|TheRest]`.

Answer (score 0):

Most recursive rules have a couple of special/base cases and a general case.

You have two base cases:

```
ordered( [] ) . % the empty list is ordered
ordered( [_] ) . % a list consisting of a single item is ordered.
```

And the general case:

```
ordered( [A,B|C] ) :- % a list of two or more items is ordered, IF ...
  A =< B ,            % - the first item is less than or equal to the second
  ordered( [B|C] ).   % - if the remainder of the list (less its head) is also ordered.
```

You might note that this won't actually **sort** the list for you: it will just indicate (via `success` or `failure`) whether or not the list is ordered.